# Can't run java in OSX Mountain Lion, comes up with error

Tags: java, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I need to run a jar file in my macbook pro running Mountain Lion. But I can't run java from command line. It comes up with error when I tried to check java version or help command

`Ashfaqur-Rahmans-MacBook-Pro:~ inganious$ java help`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: help
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: help
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Please anyone help .

Thanks

Comment: `java help`, if java is installed correctly, will show exactly what you have.  What are you expecting to see instead?  (Do you mean `java -help`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) take class file name as its parameter. When you type `java help`, the JVM thinks `help` is a class file name, and it throws the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception because it doesn't find it.

What you are trying to do is using the help option.

```
java -help
```